# Connection closed by application error when iterating through cursor and updating documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following simple node.js app which creates cursor from query which sorts collectoin by City and then temperature. After that, I iterate through cursor and update every document with highest temperatures for every city by adding highest : true.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/temp', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var cursor = db.collection('data').find().sort( { City : 1,  Temperature : -1 } );

    var previous = '';

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) { 
        if(err) throw err;

        if(doc == null) {
            console.dir("Closing database connection"); 
            return db.close();
        }
        if (previous != doc.City) {
            previous = doc.City;

            var query = { _id : doc._id };
            var operator = { '$set' : { highest : true } };

            console.dir(doc.City + " is " + doc.Temperature + "; ");


            db.collection('data').update(query, operator, function(err, updated) {
                if(err) {
                    console.error('Error:', err);
                    throw err;
                }


                console.dir("Successfully updated: " + JSON.stringify(updated));    
            });    
        }
    });

});
```

The problem here is that only first city gets updated properly, here is the output:

> 'Berlin is 81; ' 'Successfully updated: 1' 'Paris Florida is 83; '
>   'Warsaw New Mexico is 57; ' 'Barcelona Vermont is 57; ' 'Closing
>   database connection' Error: { [MongoError: Connection Closed By
>   Application] name: 'MongoError' } Error: { [MongoError: Connection
>   Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError' } Error: { [MongoError:
>   Connection Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError' }

My guess on what is happening is: the cursor goes through all documents calls update on those with highest temperatures:

```
db.collection('data').update(query, operator, function(err, updated)
```

but before the callback returns, cursor finishes iterating and this fragment of code is called which closes connection:

```
if(doc == null) {
            console.dir("Closing database connection"); 
            return db.close();
        }
```

after that, all updates which didn't finish processing will error out since no db connection is available.

What's the proper way of handling it so that connection is closed only after all documents are updated successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Neil mentioned, we can use .stream(), but I was able to make the program execute as expected by counting already processed updates and closing db connection after all documents which we expect to be updated were updated.
In my case it was pretty simple since I have only 4 cities in database, so I expect only 4 documents to be updated. We could also obtain this number through the query and counting results, but that's good enough for me.

Here's the working code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/temp', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var cursor = db.collection('data').find().sort( { City : 1,  Temperature : -1 } );

    var previous = '';
    var updatedCount = 0;
    var expectedToUpdate = 4; // Hardcoded, but we might want to obtain it pragmatically

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) { 
        if(err) throw err;

        if(doc == null) { 
            return
        }
        if (previous != doc.City) {
            previous = doc.City;

            var query = { _id : doc._id };
            var operator = { '$set' : { highest : true } };

            console.dir(doc.City + " is " + doc.Temperature + "; ");


            db.collection('data').update(query, operator, function(err, updated) {
                if(err) {
                    console.error('Error:', err);
                    throw err;
                }


                console.dir("Successfully updated: " + JSON.stringify(updated));    
                updatedCount++;
                if (updatedCount == expectedToUpdate) {
                    console.dir("updated expected number of documents. Closing db.");
                    db.close();
                }
            });    
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually find the [node stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) interface to be a better option for an iterator. There is a [`.stream()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/cursor.html#stream) method on the cursor object for this:

```
var stream = db.collection('data').find().sort( 
    { City : 1,  Temperature : -1 } 
).stream();

stream.on('data',function(data) {
  // do things with current document
  // but pause on things with a callback then resume;

  stream.pause();
  db.collection('data').update(query, operator, function(err, updated) {
      // resume the stream when this callback is done
      stream.resume();
  })
});

stream.on('end',function() {
    // Called when everything is complete
    // db.close is safe here as long as you are no longer using the connection
    db.close();
});
```

In fact from [version 2.0](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/) of the native driver the stream interface is part of the default cursor object.

But in general, only call `db.close()` for one off processing scripts. You should generally not be calling it at all in server type implementations and just leaving the connection open over the life-cycle.